# Import Dask Dataframe into Bigquery Table?

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery, dask

Is there any technique to upload dask dataframe into bigquery table?
Bigquery supports pandas as far as I know.

Suppose we have df as pandas dataframe:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
bq_table_path=`project_id.dataset_id.table_name`
bigquery_client=bigquery.client(project=project_id)
bigquery_client.load_table_from_dataframe(df,bq_table_path)
```

What about in dask dataframe?
I got the following errors:

```
NotImplemented Error: series getitem is only supported for other series objects with matching partition structure"
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I recently prototyped something that you can find in this comment on a github issue https://github.com/coiled/dask-bigquery/issues/3#issuecomment-896350178 but if you keep reading the discussion, there are limitations with this implementation, mainly related to the size of the data.
If you have a big amount of data and you can rely on intermediate storage and use parquet you can try to follow the solution on this gist https://gist.github.com/bnaul/4819f045ccbee160b60a530b6cfc0c98#file-dask_bigquery-py-L188-L271

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal, but one possibility is to make this a serial process via something like this:

```py
for df_subset in df.partitions:
    df_pandas = df_subset.compute()
    bigquery_client.load_table_from_dataframe(df_pandas,bq_table_path)
```

However, for many contexts this might be very inefficient due to data transfer and one-at-a-time processing.

Comment: Why not `map_partitions` ?

Comment: Ah, I am not sure if bigquery supports parallel writes... thinking about it now I guess it should... so in that case `map_partitions` is a much better solution.

Comment: If we use ```map_partitions``` do we need to assign columns? This process should be automated. Any example to illustrate ```map_partitions``` on above example?

Comment: ```df.paritions``` is memory intensive. Is there other technique that could support more TB of data?